# Transaction took too long

Tags: action, mainnet

I occurred this Error 3080006: transaction took too long when push my own contract action. the push action cmd had no setting '-X'.
It's weird because I pushed the same action with two different accounts，one is ok but another occured frequently.

the -u setting is :https://api.eosnewyork.io
Can anyone help me how to analysis this weird question?

Thanks in advance,
harlin

Comment: maybe the other account has less cpu or it attempted to transact during congestion times

Comment: today I occurred this error for just one account but it had enough cpu to execute the action. I can see the action is executed from EOSPark, but the cmd returns 'transaction took too long' at the execute moment。

Answer (score 1):

### Abstract

This maybe related to **the hardware the blockproducer performing the transaction is using**. So I guess you know about the time limit (~ 150ms) which is used to guarantee the high block rates. So staking the right amount of CPU is just a part.

### Example

Imagine this scenario with a tx time limit of 1000ms instead of 150ms:

- BP A is using a CPU with 1 GHz = 1 * 10^9 Hz
- BP B is using a CPU with 1.5 GHz = 1.5 * 10^9 Hz

**If your transaction needs about 1.1 * 10^9 CPU cycles or instructions this will fit in the time slot for BP B**, because he can handle 1.5 * 10^9 CPU cycles in 1 second. But **for BP A it fail** because he can only handle 1 * 10^9 CPU cycles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man. I double checked my contract method and optimized some code about table query which effected the account searching result.  And it's worked for me.

Comment: Glad you solved it. If you are satisfied with this answer please mark it as accepted so others can find it better as well.